# Creating a private/public key with 64 characters that are already known using bitcoinjs

Tags: bitcoin, ecdsa

So I'm trying to create a private/public key from 64 characters that I already know using bitcoinjs with the code below:

```
key = Bitcoin.ECKey.makeRandom();

// Print your private key (in WIF format)
document.write(key.toWIF());
// => Kxr9tQED9H44gCmp6HAdmemAzU3n84H3dGkuWTKvE23JgHMW8gct

// Print your public key (toString defaults to a Bitcoin address)
document.write(key.pub.getAddress().toString());
// => 14bZ7YWde4KdRb5YN7GYkToz3EHVCvRxkF
```

If I try to set "key" to my 64 characters instead of "Bitcoin.ECKey.makeRandom();" it fails. Is there a method or library that I overlooked that would allow me to use the known 64 characters in order to generate the private key in wif format and the public address?
Thanks in advance to anyone that may be able to offer some help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use fromWIF method to pass your own data.

from source code of eckey.js

```
// Static constructors
ECKey.fromWIF = function(string) {
  var payload = base58check.decode(string)
  var compressed = false

  // Ignore the version byte
  payload = payload.slice(1)

  if (payload.length === 33) {
    assert.strictEqual(payload[32], 0x01, 'Invalid compression flag')

    // Truncate the compression flag
    payload = payload.slice(0, -1)
    compressed = true
  }
```

To create WIF from your key please follow https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format
Here is interactive tool http://gobittest.appspot.com/PrivateKey

Answer (score 0):

The solution to generate private and public key:

```
//public-key
var address = eckey.getBitcoinAddress().toString();

var privateKeyBytesCompressed = privateKeyBytes.slice(0); 
privateKeyBytesCompressed.push(0x01);
var privateKeyWIFCompressed = new Bitcoin.Address(privateKeyBytesCompressed);
privateKeyWIFCompressed.version = 0x80;


//private-key
privateKeyWIFCompressed = privateKeyWIFCompressed.toString();
```

Take a look at moneyart.info for beautifully designed paperwallets.